# Is it possible to access a Public Class Member from outside of the main() where it is created?

Tags: c++, class

I am a newbie in c++ and today I was trying to make access a public class member outside of main(), more exactly in another function.

I tried to create pointer to that class, but I fail at accessing its members. I am going to show an example with a few lines of code, Any help would be appreciated.

```
Class City
{
private:
    string name;

public:
    string getName()
    {
        return name; 
    }
};

bool isCity(string input)
{
    if(input== ???) { return true; } 
    return false; 
}
```

*The problem: how to access public member getName() from the class I create in main() at the question marks

```
int main()
{

    string input;
    City test;

    cin >> input;

    isCity(input);

    cin.get();
}
```

The pointer to Class is not working, the reference pass isn't working either.

Comment: Why isn't `isCity` apart of the `City` class? Or pass an instance of `City` as a parameter

Comment: @GBlodgett I meant to write it out of the City class, sorry for that

Comment: You need an object (instance) of the `City` class to be able to call member functions. And if you want to check if the "name" of a `City` happens to be equal to the "input", then first of all you need a [collection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of `City` object you search through.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to have isCity part of the class and call it as a method of the object `test.isCity(input);`

The class should be as follow:

```
Class City
{
private:
    std::string name;

public:
    std::string getName() const
    {
        return name; 
    }

    bool isCity(const std::string& input) const
    {
        return input.compare(name) == 0
    }
};
```

Else you could have a free function (outside of the class), but the signature should provide the class `city` object as follow:

```
bool isCity(const City& c, const std::string& input)
{
    return input.compare(c.GetName()) == 0;
}
```

Which then means you have to call the function as follow:

```
isCity(test, input);
```